# Different results with MACS2 when Peakcalling with .bed or .bam

Tags: bioinformatics, bam, bed, bedtools

I got the following problem: 
I use MACS2 (2.1.0.20140616) with the following short commandline:

```
macs2 callpeak -t file.bam -f bam -g 650000000 -n Test -B --nomodel -q 0.01
```

It seems to work as I want, but when I convert the .bamfile into .bed via

```
bedtools bamtobed -i file.bam > file.bed
```

and use MACS2 on this, I get a lot more peaks. As far as I understand, the .bed-file should contain the same information as the .bam-file, so that's kinda odd.

Any suggestions what's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to tag the appropriate languages and frameworks. It will be hard for people to help you otherwise.